# When type "any" is not compatible with other types

Tags: typescript

I don't understand why these two static methods are not compatible with each other.
As I understand type `any` is compatible with anything. Consider this example.

```js
class A {
    static createInstance<T=any>(data:T):A {
        return new A()
    }
}

class B extends A{
    constructor(public role: string = 'manager') {
        super()
    }
    static createInstance<T extends { role: string }>(data:T): B{
        return new B(data.role)
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Class static side 'typeof B' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof A'.
  Types of property 'createInstance' are incompatible.
    Type '<T extends { role: string; }>(data: T) => B' is not assignable to type '<T = any>(data: T) => A'.
      Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
        Type 'T' is not assignable to type '{ role: string; }'.
```

My thinking is that if I use `any` as type in the parent class (`A`) I can do whatever I like in child classes (`B`). So I'm not really sure what is going on.
Also, if I change `createInstance` method signature in class `A` to:

```
createInstance(data:any):A
```

Then I get no errors.

I am really puzzled with this.

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=2#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa7oQC5iwS2GmACcBTXUgSQDtsxrhSAeAFQF56BPAPgAoATXGABcLAJTD4yNBllksAV2LVo1UgHc4vMalkBfVAZSpQkGACFopAB5ZS1fjFjTZwAPa0sxBcCxvivAAOCgBGIATQxG4gpMKYXnjUAObQbNAA5AC29GBJpMTpYoi6shgQCoH52iXoRrJ0+IQk5HY0dAzMLFa29o6IkdGx8cSJKXp8gjiiEtDmLqXo8koqaprmAkIAdFExOjK1hkA)

Comment: This is an rightly an error. The reason is that the type constraint in the subtype method, and thereby the type of its parameter, is more restrictive than that of the supertype. Therefore, the subtype can not act in place of the supertype. If you were to put the more restrictive constraint on the supertype, and the less restrictive on the subtype, it would be perfectly valid because the subtype allows more not less.

Comment: I don't understand why this code: `createInstance(data:any):A` is not an error?

Comment: `any` universally bivariant. It is assignable to _and_ from all other types. If you use `any`. Using `any` as a type _annotation_ means the compiler can not validate the types.

Comment: Also note that `<T = any>(x: T)` is very different from `(x: any)` because, of type inference.